# javascript validation numerical

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi sorry i'm still pretty new to javascript.

I've developed a form in HTML and now i'm attempting to add javascript to validate the form.

So far i have simple javascript to make sure each element is filled in,

```
    if (document.order.suburb.value=="")
    {
        alert("Suburb Cannot Be Empty")
        return false
    }   

if (document.order.postcode.value=="")
    {
        alert("Postcode Cannot Be Empty")
        return false
    }
```

I then have javascript to validate the length of some of the elements,

```
    if (document.order.telephone.value.length < 10) 
    { 
        alert("Invalid Telephone Number") 
        return false 
    }
```

Now i'm trying to validate numeric values in the telephone number part but it's not executing correctly, it's like the code is just ignored when it's being executed.

```
var digits="0123456789"
var temp
var i   

for (i = 0 ; i <document.order.telephone.value.length; i++)
    { 
    temp=document.order.telephone.value.substring(i,i+1) 
if (digits.indexOf(temp)==-1)
    { 
        alert("Invalid Telephone Number")
        return false
    }
    }
```

Thanks for reading and thanks for the help :) been stuck on this issue for weeks and have no idea what i'm doing wrong, i tried to code on a separate document with another form and it seemed to work fine.

EDIT

Code for validation for digits in postcode

```
  var post = document.order.postcode.value.replace(white,'');

  if(!post){
    alert("Post code required !");
    return false;
  }

   post = post.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');//replace all other than digits
  if(!post || 4 > postcode.length) {
    alert("Invalid Postcode !");
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: May want to look at regular expressions for this.

Comment: `if (/[^0-9]/.test(temp)) { /* failed validation */ }`

Comment: you want to stay away from `alert` and use `console.log` and friends (`.info`, `.warn` and `.error`) instead. This writes the debug message to the browser console, without locking up the page, or even the browser.

Comment: @PaulS. i've replaced my code 'if (digits.indexOf(temp)==-1)' with yours and it doesn't seem to validate the numbers still.

Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so instead of alert i can write console.warn ("Invalid Card Number") and this will alert the user of their accidental mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this example:

```js
var validate = function() {
  var white = /\s+/g;//for handling white spaces
  var nonDigit = /[^0-9]/g; //for non digits
  if(!document.order.suburb.value.replace(white, '')) {
    alert("Suburb required !");
    return false; //don't allow to submit
  }
  var post = document.order.postcode.value.replace(white, '')
  if(!post) {
    alert("Post code required !");
    return false;
  }
  post = post.replace(nonDigit,'');//replace all other than digits
  if(!post || 6 > post.length) { //min post code length
    alert("Invalid Post code !");
    return false;
  }
  var tel = document.order.telephone.value.replace(white, '');
  if(!tel) {
    alert("Telephone required !");
    return false;
  }
  tel = tel.replace(nonDigit,'');
  if(!tel || 10 > tel.length) {
    alert("Invalid Telephone !");
    return false;
  }
  return true; //return true, when above validations have passed
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate();" action="#" name="order">
  Suburb: <input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb" ><br/>
  Post code: <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"/><br/>
  Telephone: <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone"/><br/>
  <input type="reset"/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i implemented the code above into my form and i worked, but when i tried to do the same validation for postcode it did not work and also did not allow the telephone validation to work either. It would always come up with ' Invalid Telephone !' even if i write a number that worked before

Comment: @Naddy, can you please update your post with the latest code?

Comment: done, but i deleted the code that i had before that because it was not working, i tried to recreate it again

Comment: I've also just edited ur code for other text elements such as email address and first name/last name and they work fine, it then runs up to the postcode validtion point, give ms and error until i type something like '3675'. Then just 'submits' the form

Comment: Thanks so much it's working now just need to add a bit more for the rest of the form :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/45jn6u62/) that will give you something to think about.

You could handle this task in hundreds of ways. I've just used a regex and replaced all of the non-numbers with '' - and compared the length of two variables - if there is anything other than a number the length of the regex variable will be shorter than the unchanged mytelephone.

You can do all kinds of "validation" - just me very specific in how you define "valid".

JS

```
var mysuburb, mypostcode, mytelephone;

$('.clickme').on('click', function(){

    mysuburb = $('.suburb').val();
    mypostcode = $('.postcode').val();
    mytelephone = $('.telephone').val();
    console.log(mysuburb + '--' + mypostcode + '--' + mytelephone);

    if(mysuburb.length < 1)
      {
       $('.errorcode').html('');
       $('.errorcode').append('Suburb is required');
       return false;
       }
    if(mypostcode.length < 1)
      {
       $('.errorcode').html('');
       $('.errorcode').append('postode is required');
       return false;
       }
    if( mytelephone.length < 1 )
      {
       $('.errorcode').html('');
       $('.errorcode').append('telephone number is required');
       return false;
       }
    if( mytelephone.length != mytelephone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length) 
      {
       $('.errorcode').html('');
       $('.errorcode').append('telephone number must contain only numbers');
       return false;
       }   
});
```